# Why MySQL server does not write table to files?

Tags: mysql, windows, memory, file, insert

Recently, I write a python code to insert HTML text into table. After my code writing about 200,000 html page, I can use select to retrieval all these data. However, I find that the MySQL server does not write any data into files. I check the memory usage and find that mysqld.exe program consumes more than 1.5GB memory. I search the whole disk about the table name but I only found a 9KB file related to my table name. By the way, I also checked the mysql.ini file. The path configuration is correct. Then, I use mysqldump to backup that table. This command gives me more than 7GB sql file. I check it again and find there is 20GB file ibdata in my datadir folder. What is that file mean? Why there is no file related to my table ? Does MySQL just store the data in memory?

Comment: What kind of table did you use? Mysql supports temporary and in-memory-only table types, as well as linked tables in other databases (federated table type). Normally MySQL would commit data to disk as soon as possible in case of system failure. If nothing's on disk after 200,000 rows, shutting down your machine will lose the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're on InnoDB but haven't enabled `innodb_file_per_table`, so everything's being written to one file.

Answer (score 1):

Run `SHOW TABLE STATUS` and check the storage engine value.  It might be using `MEMORY`, though I would be surprised if it is and you didn't know that (because you would have to set it explicitly).